# Change personal Gmail account to use own domain name

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I really like Gmail as an email provider, mainly because its spam settings seem to be so much 'smarter' than most other services. At the moment I've have a personal Gmail account (not a Google Apps for Business) and I have a domain.

In the past I would have just set up a Google Apps for Business account, but they've started charging for them (as of today - [Techcrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/12/07/google-kills-free-google-apps-for-business-now-only-offering-premium-paid-version-to-companies-of-all-sizes/)).

Is there a way I can set up my normal Gmail account - `mycompany@gmail.com` to be `mycompany@example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Operating System:

> Apparently, there's a workaround that lets you use the free version of Google Apps for a single account. "If you create a new Apps account going through the [App Engine Admin Console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain?hl=en) you'll still be able to create a Standard Apps account for free but you'll only be able to get 1 user per account rather than the 10 you get today," says Greg D'Alesandre, Senior Product Manager for Google App Engine.

[Reference](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-apps-no-longer-free-for-small.html).

Comment: ive given that a try, what you end up with is a free google app engine account, but i couldnt see a way to confirgure the emails

Answer (score 0):

Goto [google.com/takeout](http://google.com/takeout) with your Gmail account and tranfer your Google+ circles to your new account.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, all you have to do is go to example.com and create an email address mycompany@example.com and then have all email to that address forwarded to your Gmail.
I have almost 100 different email addresses at example.com, all forwarded to my Gmail.

Comment: i meant more allong the lines of changing it via the mx record so that myname@mydomain.com would be the actual email, not a forwarded address